# Build WORHP on osx

Tags: worhp

I would like to try `worhp` with `scip`. I first tried building the examples by using `Makefile` give in `worhp 1.14`. I get this message when compiling with `Makefile`:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file lib/libworhp.so, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 )
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CheckWorhpVersion", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_DoneUserAction", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_GetUserAction", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_InitParams", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_IterationOutput", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_ReadParamsNoInit", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_StatusMsg", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_Worhp", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_WorhpFidif", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_WorhpFree", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_WorhpInit", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
  "_WorhpPreInit", referenced from:
      _main in c-example.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Is there any way to use the library on Mac osx?

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not officially support macOS at the moment. However, if you send me a message via the contact form on our website worhp.de I may be able to compile a build for your system.

Comment: At the moment, I have successfully compiled on a linux machine. I would also like to make a note that the build requires a certain version of gcc, not supporting a higher version at least on my machine.